# Re-inheriting permissions from parent SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, roles, splist

So I know how to break inheritance from a list (SPList.BreakRoleInheritance(true)), but how do you reinherit from it's parent programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.resetroleinheritance.aspx).

> SPList.ResetRoleInheritance();

Answer (score 2):

As an end point URL here is an example of how to do it via JQuery Ajax function -

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "*Site URL here*/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('*your list name here*')/items(*item ID here*)/ResetRoleInheritance()",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Permissions successful applied to list item!');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Failed!');
            }
        });
```